# magento one step checkout switch billing and shipping address section

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I am using onestepcheckout.com onestepcheckout.

As per our requirement, I need to switch Billing & Shipping address section in OneStepCheckout.

Basic requirement is that, First user will fill shipping address and give checkbox option to “Bill to same address”. If user checked the checkbox, then Shipping Address will treat as billing address and if unchecked then Billing address section will open and user will fill the details.

Can anyone guide, where I need to change/update code to achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to program the missing parts as magento does not allow easy customisation of address objects and has only implemented one way of using those billing first  then shipping and core can fill shipping address with billing data but not vice versa. On top of that billing and shipping addresses have different amount of fields to fill and what's mandatory for billing are missing in shipping etc.

Everything is possible tho but this task is just time-consuming to build the missing logic to verify both addresses are getting filled.